# Garageband Static When Switching from Stereo to Mono

Tags: stereo, mono, garageband

When pulling a stereo-track mp3 into Garageband with only one channel, before this latest update to 10.2.0, if I changed the input source from stereo to mono, there was no issue. However, after this update, when I change the track input from stereo to mono, I'm getting a staticky crackle at various points in the track. Is there a solution to this? Are others getting the same issue?